# Xcode couldn't open the project generated by cordova-ios": "6.1.1" but "5.1.0" is Okay

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfzEe.jpg)

Xcode error message is:workspace integrity couldn't load project,but when i use cordova plugin 'cordova-ios@5.1.0',Xcode was ok to load the project.

Does anyone know why?I was stuck in this for a quite long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open xcodeworkspace, intead of project.

Comment: May i ask what's the difference btw these two options